# How can I add an already existing VPC to a lambda using AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk-typescript

Currently I'm using AWS CDK to create a simple lambda function.

```
const hello = new Function(this,"HelloHandler",{
      role:lambdaRole,
      runtime:Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      code:Code.fromAsset("dist"),
      handler:"index.handler",
    })
```

I wish to add a VPC to the lambda. Normally one would need to create a VPC [in the normal manner](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-lambda-function-vpc). However in my scenario, I wish to add a VPC that already exists and was created using the AWS console.

Is there a way to do so?

Note:

- I'm using TypeScript

Comment: Add vpc as a parameter of your cdk stack

Comment: Yes, use the `Vpc.fromVpcAttributes` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what if I want to also add subnets and security groups that already exist

Comment: You will still be able to do that.